# relationship between a function and its inverse

Tags: functions

I did some observation about a function and its inverse and I would like to confirm whether these observation are true:

1. The domain and range roles of the inverse and function are 'exchanged'
2. The graph of inverse function is flipped 90degree as compared to the function.
3. x is treated like y, y is treated like x in its inverse.

is it always the case?

Comment: 1. Yes, that's how an invertible function's inverse is defined. For example, if we have $f:A\to B$ such that $f$ is one-to-one and onto, then $f^{-1}:B\to A$
2. The graphs are symmetrical with respect to the straight line f(x)=x if I'm correct.
3. Do not understand the proposition.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences are true except 2nd one: the function $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ are symmetrical with respect to the line $y=x$. It follows directly from your 3rd point.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 and 3 are correct but it's not that it gets rotated 90 degrees, the inverse is a reflection over the line y=X from the parent function.